# Age using YEAR mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with Horse (varchar), Born (year), Died (year). I need to calculate the age of the horse. I can do it using INT, however i have to do it using YEAR. Can anyone give me any guidance?

Comment: Is `YEAR` not an `INT`?

Comment: SELECT horse_Id, Name, (YEAR(CURDATE()) - Born) from horse; finally got it.

Comment: The query i had working when the fields where INT would not work when i changed it to YEAR, I was using simple subtraction for INT.

Answer (score 1):

```
select datediff(year,born,died)
```

Comment: select horse_id, datediff (born,died) as Age from horse; returns as NULL

Comment: data type for born,died is it only year ? or date ? `select horse_id, datediff (year,born,died) as Age from horse try this`

Comment: its only a year,i figured it out, thanks for our help

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to subtract it in the select statement?

```
SELECT Died - Born FROM yourTableName
```

Then you can just add additional WHERE statement so filter the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that:

```
SELECT Horse, (died - born) as Age
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT horse, (die - born) as age
FROM `your table`
```